# UIWebView with offline access

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need a smart UIWebView (or a similar component) that can display/cache the full content of an HTML page on my server along with the images for offline access. And as soon as internet becomes available it will load the live version.

The app is a membership directory with member profiles. There's a main index and a page for each member.

Can you guys guide me to the right path on how to develop something like this? or point me to an existing library.

Thanks for your help I'm to new iOS development.

Comment: have you got to the point where you are successfully loading the live content when you are online?

Comment: @bshirley yes I can load a live web page using UIWebView

Answer (score 1):

Two paths I can think of:

- Wrap UIWebView, either in a subclass or a category, to encapsulate the loading logic

  1. If network is online, load the URL directly and caching it using [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the URL string as the key. NSURLConnection or something like [EGOHTTPRequest](https://github.com/enormego/EGOHTTPRequest) will make loading easy.
  2. If network is offline, check if the data exists in the cache. If so, use the -loadData: method to pull the content out of the cache and render it in the WebView. If it doesn't exist, display an error
- Use a caching HTTP library, like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to load the data. It can cache data it has loaded internally, and serve those cached results on subsequent requests if the network is offline.

ASIHTTPRequest looks a lot better on the surface, however there is a possible downside: It is a completely reimplemented URL loading system, based on very low level constructs (CFNetwork). So as Apple makes improvements to their high level libraries (NSURLConnection, NSCache) ASIHTTP doesn't get those advancements. Also, since so much of it's code is in Foundation, it will be a pretty major project to port it to ARC when that becomes generally available.

Answer (score 0):

To load a local file on a UIWebView use `fileURLWithPath`

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Comment: what about images, css, js files? does it method only cache the html page?

Comment: This piece of code only shows a local html file on a UIWebView for caching you might want to save the data using SQLite the first time the app connects.

Answer (score 0):

It sure seems like you need to look at `ASIWebPageRequest`, which lets you cache whole pages offline:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest